# how to call kernel in .cpp file?

Tags: cuda, c++17, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use CUDA to accelerate the current project. I have written the kernel methods and I want to call it in a file (.cpp or.cu) while the main function exists in another C++ project. I will compile it using g++ in Visual Studio. However, some errors occur during the project compilation:

```
 error : ‘threadIdx’ was not declared in this scope.

 error : ‘blockIdx’ was not declared in this scope.

 error : ‘gridDim’ was not declared in this scope.


 error : static assertion failed: unimplemented for this system.
```

Comment: Those errors come from trying to compile CUDA kernel code with a regular C++ compiler. That is impossible. You must use a CUDA syntax aware compiler like nvcc or clang

Comment: How can I link a CUDA kernel (.o) file after compiling it with the nvcc compiler to a C++ project?

Comment: Normally one writes a CPU "wrapper" function that does the kernel launch using the right launch parameters (grid an block dimensions). Linking against that function with the host linker should be straightforward. I.e. the kernel function itself is not part of the API, just the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

A file that contains kernels must be named *.cu or .cuh for headers. And you need to use nvcc as compiler.